# How can I read console output on my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to read console output (like console.error("error");)
on my javascript code(on run time) when error has occurred

Comment: Try to catch exceptions not to catch the console outputs.. Purpose of console is only to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use try catch blocks to handle the errors, this is for your better understanding

**HTML**

```
<div id="display2">Welcome to my world!</div>
<button class="btn" id="btnRes" onclick="displayMessage()"> Check It Out </button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function welcome() {
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "Welcome to my world!";
}
$('#btnRes').click(function() {
  try {
    wel_come();
  } catch (error) {
    document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = error.message;
  }
});
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/PrakashS/0bm3cavL/)

Answer (score 0):

Just override / proxy the original function like:

```
console.log = (function(original){
    return function proxyLog(){
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        // do something with args
        // then call the original function
        original.apply(console, arguments);
    }
}(console.log)); // invoke iife
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the console output on Google Chrome, press F12 or right-click, Inspect, then click on the Console tab which is next to the Elements tab to view console output. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for